# How can I make this merge sort code to work, currently it just returns the same input array

Tags: c++

I've been trying to code the merge sort algorithm for two days now and it's just not working, can you please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

here's the merge function I created to merge the two arrays after partition

```
void merge(int array[], int si, int mid, int ei)
{
    int size1=mid+1, size2=ei-mid, i=0, j=0, k=0;
    int array1[size1], array2[size2], main_arr[k];

    for (int s = 0; s < size1; s++)
    {
        array1[s]=array[si+s];
    }

    for (int t = 0; t < size2; t++)
    {
        array2[t]=array[mid+t+1];
    }

    while (i<size1 && j<size2)
    {
        if (array1[i]<array2[j])
        {
            main_arr[k]=array1[i];
            k++, i++;
        }
        else
        {
            main_arr[k]=array2[j];
            k++, j++;
        }

    }
    while (i<size1)
    {
        main_arr[k]=array1[i];
        k++, i++;
    }
    while (j<size2)
    {
        main_arr[k]=array2[j];
        k++, j++;
    }
    
}
```

and here's the mergeSort function which is dividing the main array into two smaller arrays using recursion.

```
void mergeSort (int array[], int si, int ei)
{
    if (si<ei)
    {
        int mid=(si+ei)/2;
        mergeSort(array, si, mid);
        mergeSort(array, mid+1, ei);

        merge(array, si, mid, ei);

    }
    
}
```

and this is the main function

```
int main () {
    int array[6]= {6,5,4,3,2,1};
    cout << " The sorted array is " << endl;
    mergeSort(array, 0, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

Would really appreciate the help,
Thank you!

Comment: You write to some temporary arrays which you discard. Further, those arrary are variable-length arrays, which is not standard C++ but a compiler extension. Also, allocating with `new[]` is bad, use `std::vector` instead. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You never modify `array`

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty much to explain. The general idea is splitting your array while you get 1-size or 2-size small subarray, swap the elements of that array and repeat for the next one and then merge two subarrays. Hope, the following code will help you a bit.

```
vector<int>& mergeSort(vector<int>& array, int start, int end) {
  if(end - start == 1)
    return array;
  if(end - start == 2) {
    int tmp = array[0];
    array[0] = array[1];
    array[1] = tmp;
    return array;
  }
  int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
  vector<int>& arr1 = mergeSort(array, start, mid);
  vector<int>& arr2 = mergeSort(array, mid + 1, end);
  vector<int>& merged = merge(arr1, arr2);
  return merged;
}

vector<int>& merge(vector<int>& arr1, vector<int>& arr2) {
  vector<int> output;
  int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
  while(n1 < arr1.size() || n2 < arr2.size()) {
    if(n1 == arr1.size()) {
      output.push_back(arr2[n2]); ++n2;
      continue;
    }
    if(n2 == arr2.size()) {
      output.push_back(arr1[n1]); ++n1;
      continue;
    }
    output.push_back( (arr1[n1] > arr2[n2] ? arr2[n2++] : arr1[n1++]) );
  }
  return output;
}
```

[image]

I would also recommend to debug your program and follow the above diagram to better understand the process of merging sort.